# Rails: Refactor dynamic paths using variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

Any idea how could I refactor this code?

```
case @fruit.actable_type
            when "Apple"
                redirect_to apple_path(@fruit.specific, :anchor => "comment_id_#{@comment.id}")
            when "Orange"
                redirect_to orange_path(@fruit.specific, :anchor => "comment_id_#{@comment.id}")
            when "Banana"
                redirect_to banana_path(@fruit.specific, :anchor => "comment_id_#{@comment.id}")
            end
```

The main problem is that to specify the anchor I need to include the path, I cannot do just this:

```
redirect_to @fruit.specific, anchor: "whatever"
```

I tried a lot of things, but still I couldnn't refactor that :/

Answer (score 2):

```
path_method = "#{@fruit.actable_type.downcase}_path"
anchor = "comment_id_{@comment.id}"
redirect_to send(path_method, @fruit.specific, anchor: anchor)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. The method send it was the key to solve it!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you:

```
anchor = "comment_id_#{@comment.id}"
prefix = @fruit.actable_type.downcase
redirect_to send("#{prefix}_path", @fruit.specific, anchor: anchor)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. The method send it was the key to solve it!